# Post image to wall user twitter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, twitter, oauth-2.0

I know that it's possible to post an image in the wall of user twitter using TweetWithMedia,

the question is : it's possible to post just an url and twitter detect that is an image? without using TweetWithMedia (TweetWithMedia upload the image, i don't want to upload the image)

thanks,

Comment: Twitter wall? Don't you think you should know how Twitter works, before trying to interface with it?

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt I posted on the wall of a twitter user with TweetWithMedia, the problem is that it loads the image bit by bit, I don't want the image DOWNLOADED TO twitter

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt send tweet to my folowers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use the normal `statuses/update` endpoint to upload the tweet which includes a link to the image. Then implement the new [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards) feature to get them linked as images.

Comment: I want when I send a tweet that contains a url of an image, Twitter display the image and not the url, thanks

Comment: That's what the cards are for.

Comment: I put this code in the view but I get nothing in twitter : <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2012/02/19/us/19whitney-span/19whitney-span-articleLarge.jpg" />